# Is there a way to hide the BitDefender black rectangle added over the web page?

Tags: firefox

Is this possible to hide this annoying black rectangle in the top center of webpage in firefox that is added by BitDefender?

There is no extension or addon to Firefox. This sliding window does not appear on Chrome and  safari, but well on IE and Firefox.

[image]

Comment: You can disable the plugin that creates it.  If you don't have that permissin you are out of luck.  A previous question indicates there is no configuration offered for this feature.

Comment: I don't see any plugins (extension) in firefox concerning bitDefender...

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a new tab on firefox and enter: `about:plugins`
2. Search for "Bitdefender" with `Ctrl + F` and copy the location of the plugin
3. Close Firefox, delete the file on that location and reopen Firefox again

*Side note:*
Sometimes some plugins get recreated by the software related to it. If this happens after deleting the file, follow the same procedure again, but before opening Firefox, go back on the location of the file and on the folder that contains it, `right-click` > `Properties` and select "Read only" and then select OK and open Firefox.

*If it is a toolbar:*
**Option I**
Open Bitdefender and click on Settings. Then go to 'Privacy Control' and from the Antiphishing tab set on OFF 'Show Bitdefender Toolbar'.

**Option II**
Go on Control Panel > Uninstall a program and search for "toolbar" and see if there is any toolbar related to bitdefender and uninstall it.

Comment: Nothing found about bitDefender on this in that section

Comment: It could be a toolbar. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Btw I'm not quite sure if **Option I** will be the same as that depends what bitdefender version you have. Mine is an old version. If also the second option doesn't work for you, try to modify your bitdefender installation and deselect the phishing toolbar